# SQL SELECT (many-2-many)

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to browse through previously asked question for my problem, but there are SO many questions. Hopefully this is not a duplicate I'm new to SQL, so still trying to wrap my head around this! BTW, I'm using MySQL.

So I have 2 tables:

```
Sickness 
id: 1, name: flu
id: 2, name: migraine

Symptom
id: 1, name: cough
id: 2, name: headache
```

and the intermediate table e.g:

```
Sickness2Symptom 
sickness_id: 1, symptom_id: 1
sickness_id: 1, symptom_id: 2
sickness_id: 2, symptom_id: 2
```

I would like a query that lists all sicknesses that do not have a relation to a specific symptom.

So if we look at retrieving all created relations between a symptom and sicknesses. Let's say the symptom has `id=1 (cough)`. That query would look like:

```
     SELECT sickness.*
     FROM sickness
     JOIN sickness2symptom
     ON sickness2symptom.sickness_id = sickness.id
     JOIN symptom
     ON symptom.id = sickness2symptom.symptom_id
     WHERE symptom.id = 1";
```

So that would return `"flu"`.

But how would I query to get all sicknesses that do not have a relation to symptom with `id 1`, in this case the result of the query would be `"migraine"`?

If I change just the `WHERE` clause to `!=1` it obviously isn't correct.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select s.*
from sickness s
where not exists (select 1
                  from Sickness2Symptom s2s
                  where s2s.sickness_id = s.id and s2s.symptom_id = 1
                 );
```

Note that you don't actually need the `symptom` table, because the information you need is in `Sickness2Symptom`.

Also, a `not exists` query can also be expressed as `NOT IN`:

```
where s.id NOT IN (select s2s.sickness_id
                   from Sickness2Symptom s2s
                   where s2s.symptom_id = 1
                  );
```

Or as `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I see the solution it is obvious. I was overcomplicating things in my head :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed (a couple minutes left until I get to accept)

Comment: And you only need the aliases in the subquery to reference the outer query, the query processor assumes the current (inner) query table unless explicitly pointed elsewhere. So shorter, using default names would be:   `select * from sickness s where not exists (select * from Sickness2Symptom where sickness_id = s.id and symptom_id = 1)`